# Adding of a UILabel on UIImage view in ios

Tags: ios6

I need to add a UILabel on UIImageview like in the right hand side corner of UIImageview and need to add the value of UILabel from JSON.

Comment: yes I tried [imageview addSubView:labelHere];

Comment: got result,it was a just silly mistake I was doing .sorry buddy